# Как сравнить вещественные числа в Си на больше-меньше?

Tags: c

Как в Си выяснить, какое из вещественных чисел больше?

Везде пишут, что нельзя использовать обычные операторы сравнения, но внятного объяснения, как корректно это сделать, я так и не нашел.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь операторами `>`, `<`. Их можно использовать с вещественными числами в C.

Comment: Ещё никто не запостил эту ссылку? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 14):

Трудности сравнения возникают, когда нужно проверить два числа на равенство - в этом случае, следует отталкиваться от конкретной задачи - математическая постановка задачи должна подсказать, достаточно ли сравнить модуль разности с заранее выбранной величиной, отвечающей за точность сравнения (абсолютной погрешностью). Подходит, например, если задача хорошо переведена в безразмерный вид, и все числа в ней принимают значения между -1 и 1.

Или использовать более сложные способы сравнения - 
[например](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=89), смешение абсолютной и относительной погрешностей

```
if (Abs(x - y) <= Max(absTol, relTol * Max(Abs(x), Abs(y))))
```

То есть, вы можете, одним из способов сначала убедиться, что числа существенно различаются, а затем уже обычным :

`if(a>b) ... else ...`

решить вопрос, какое больше, какое - меньше.

Answer (score 5):

```
a < b-EPS
a <= b+EPS
fabs(a-b) <= EPS
```

Comment: Без объяснений что тут показано - ничего не ясно (особенно тому кто спрашивает про сравнение чисел).

Comment: Кто в теме, догадаются, а для остальных действительно стоит пояснить.

Answer (score 1):

Как представляется float в памяти? Cогласно формату IEEE 754. В этом формате число представляется тремя полями. знак -1 бит , порядок - 8 бит, мантисса (23 бита) Соответсвенно все важна сама мантисса. Она то как раз будет преобразовыватся в двоичный формат и по ней будет идти сравнивание, все, что не кратно 2 будет иметь погрешность, соответсвенно сравнивать надо до какого-то определенного знака после запятой. 
Ребята я не работаю с С и С++ и С# но логично же, что вычислите модуль их разности и сравнивайте с требуемой точностью. Если модуль разности меньше точности - числа равны. Если надо сравнить больше меньше то после модуля разности еще раз проверьте если они не равны.

Comment: Отличное вступление, а вот ответа на вопрос топикстартера "как сравнивать" - нет ...