# Почему неправильно суммируется Double

Tags: java

У меня есть такая программа:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double nominal = 1.0;
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sum += 0.1;
            System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
        }

        if (nominal == sum) {
            System.out.println("Числа равны!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Числа не равны!");
        }
    }
}
```

По смыслу, результат сложения числа в цикле должен равняться 1, но результат выходит такой..:

```
sum = 0.1
sum = 0.2
sum = 0.30000000000000004
sum = 0.4
sum = 0.5
sum = 0.6
sum = 0.7
sum = 0.7999999999999999
sum = 0.8999999999999999
sum = 0.9999999999999999
Числа не равны!
```

Почему `double` суммируется не так, как нужно?

Comment: Если вам нужна точность, то используйте `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @Arsenicum, спасибо, сейчас посмотрю.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не все числа можно точно представить в виде double, таков стандарт вычислений с плавающей запятой - [IEEE 754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)

Именно поэтому, для точных вычислений дробных чисел (деньги, единицы товара), применяют числа с фиксированной запятой, но никак не `double` или `float`.

Числа с плавающей запятой прекрасно подходят для обработки научных расчетов и численного моделирования.

[О сравнении чисел с плавающей запятой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/461475/177993)

Comment: 1. Как можно проводить научные расчеты, если результат будет неточный?
2. "Числа с фиксированной запятой" — это целы числа с типом `int`, `long` и тд.?

Comment: @bukashka101 в большинстве случаев точный результат в научных расчётах не только в принципе невозможен, но и не очень-то нужен

Comment: @bukashka101 Вещественные числа следует сравнивать с определенной точностью. Можете про это посмотреть [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496080/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), например (в разеделе про вещестенные примитивы).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, хорошо :).

Comment: @andreymal, почему? Если я считаю... количество молекул в топливе для ракеты или чем-то похожем, то тут нужна максимальная точность.

Comment: @bukashka101 думаю, для числа молекул в топливе используют более продвинутые чем double типы чисел (может, что-нибудь из [длинной арифметики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Длинная_арифметика), не знаю)

Comment: @andreymal, это я для примера. Но суть Вы поняли.