# C++ компилятор не читает дробные числа

Tags: c++

Я начинающий в с++. Решал задачи на операторах if else
Есть 2 математических задач. 1-ую выводит. а 2-нет.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float x;
    cout << "y=";
    cin >> x;
    if (x>2.3)
    {
        cout << (2.7 + (-0.27))*((2 * 2.7 - 3 * (-0.27)) + 1) << '\n';
    }
    if (x >= 2.3) {
        cout << exp(6.21) + sin(6.21)<<'\n';// Тут выбран 2.3  
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В-общем когда ввожу в stdin значение 3 выводит ответ на 1 операцию = 17.520320.... а когда ввожу 2.3 выводит только `y=` . В чем я ошибся?

Comment: Связанные вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/399420/178988 & https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461464/178988

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну не умеет компьютер представлять числа с плавающей точкой абсолютно точно!

Ваше 2.3 внутри превращается в  2.2999999523162841797... Потом преобразуется для сравнения в `double`, ну, а константа 2.3, написанная вами в программе, имея тип `double`, уже равна 2.2999999999999998224, т.е. больше введенного вами значения...

Вот если вы напишете `doble x`, то тогда ваше 2.3 превратится в то же представление, что и литерал `2.3` в программе, и равенство сработает.

Но в общем случае сравнивать на равенство числа с плавающей точкой - занятие нездоровое.

Comment: Спасибо, всё понял) Исправил ошибку.